# How to show image from json column in filament 3

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-filament

I`m using filament 3 and I use my custom method to save image
these are my codes

in productResource.php file and form method I have:

`Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('image')->maxSize(1024)->image()->storeFiles(false)->required()`

and in CreateProduct.php file:

```
protected function mutateFormDataBeforeCreate(array $data): array
    {
        $data['image'] =  Helper::saveFile('/products', $data['image'], 's3');
        return $data;
    }
```

and image column is json  format in database:

```
{"url":"https:\/\/storage.iran.liara.space\/atarbaba-public\/products\/anlfskWmx3Q1RX0nOYff6C9y9VbRfOyrJIP6N9kD.png","disk":"s
```

I must to save image only this format and in Product Model I set the image field as array format:

```
  protected $casts=[
      'image'=>'array'
    ];
```

now image show in table when I use `Tables\Columns\ImageColumn::make('image.url')` but do not show in view and edit modal .please help me